# Kotlin list.map() how to avoid ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, list, concurrentmodificationexception

I have problem with ConcurrentModificationException. Here's my part of the code :

```
    var deltaSum = 0
    arrDeltaBrainWaves.map {
         value -> deltaSum += value
   }
```

To be clear - I know why this error appears :) The problem is - I have no idea what's the solution ? Do I really need to create new temp list and put values there ? It just doesnt make sense :) Any better options, please ?

EDIT:

I changed the code to below :

```
var deltaSum = 0
                                with(arrDeltaBrainWaves.iterator()) {
                                    forEach {
                                        deltaSum += it
                                    }
                                }
                                avgDelta = deltaSum / arrDeltaBrainWaves.size
```

But problem still exists.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the Iterators

example:

```
val myCollection = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4)
val iterator = myCollection.iterator()
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    val item = iterator.next()
    //do something
}
```

this will avoid ConcurrentModificationExceptions

Comment: Unfortunatelly problem still exists. Please see edited post.

Comment: @Bartos The main reason of happening this exception is you may have some code that modifies on this array.
Just test two item and let me update about it.
first, add `Volatile` to your array and run your code inside of `Synchronized` Blocks.
seccond, could you change array to hashmap? if yes this should solve this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The ConcurrentModificationException can be avoided by using iterators. Here is kotlin way to do so:

```
with(arrDeltaBrainWaves.iterator()) {
 forEach {
    
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly problem still exists. Please see edited post.

Comment: I tried the code but I don't see any exception. Are you sure the exception is caused due in this code snippet. Can you add more of your code please?

Comment: not fixing the error

Comment: @AsthaGarg Can you show your code? May be create a new question and share the link.

Comment: noting different in my code same as this question, your answer does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the `ConcurrentModificationException` by using `MutableListIterator` in `Kotlin`

**OLD CODE :**

```
registeredListeners.forEach { it.notifyObservers() }
```

(*In my case `notifyObservers()` is removing object from the `registeredListeners` list which is the cause of the exception*)

**NEW CODE :**

```
val iterator = registeredListeners.toMutableList().listIterator()
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next().notifyObservers()
}
```

Hope it helps :)